# Java serial communication on 32 bit system

Tags: java, 32-bit, serial-communication, javax.comm, jssc

I can't get serial communication to work with my Java application on 32 bit systems, both Windows XP and 7.
I've tried jssc and all i get is "Port Busy". The solution from Oracle doesn't give "Port Busy", but it just hangs, doesn't read any data.
Everything works fine on 64 bit systems.
Any idea what i might be doing wrong that causes it not to work on 32 bit?
Other serial comm libraries that you might have used with success on 32 bit systems?
Thank you!

Comment: As I know javax.comm is no longer been in action.

Comment: But i couldn't get jssc or rxtx to work on 32 bit, and i just don't have any ideas what could be causing it.

Comment: do you have a real serial port on your computer or is it a virtual usb serial port?

Comment: it might sound stupid, but i had some issues with usb<-->serial connectors...   have you tried to unplug the usb-connector to different usb-port?

Comment: I had the same problem on different computers. It works on computers that run 64 bit systems, but not on 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a packaging problem. Somehow the serial communication library didn't get packaged right. We redid it and now everything works.

Comment: I have same problem. Can you explain what exactly you did? I've tried to remove than add again jssc.jar but the error is same whatever i do. Always port is busy.

Comment: I didn't use jssc, I ended up using rxtx. But it's not a great solution because i have to manually copy the rxtx.dll in the Java installation folder of the computer that I want to run my program on. But still, it works.